# Hyperleger Composer "namespace already exists" error on "composer archive create" command

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

when execute command:

```
composer archive create --sourceType dir --sourceName /home/testuser/test-network -a /home/testuser/test-network/dist/test-network.bna
```

I get an error:

```
Creating Business Network Archive


Looking for package.json of Business Network Definition
        Input directory: /home/testuser/test-network
/usr/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:1079
      else throw err
           ^

Error: namespace already exists
    at ModelManager.addModelFiles (/usr/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/composer-common/lib/modelmanager.js:234:31)
    at Function.fromDirectory (/usr/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/composer-common/lib/businessnetworkdefinition.js:493:43)
    at Function.handler (/usr/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/lib/cmds/archive/lib/create.js:80:42)
    at Object.module.exports.handler (/usr/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/lib/cmds/archive/createCommand.js:31:30)
    at Object.self.runCommand (/usr/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/yargs/lib/command.js:233:22)
    at Object.Yargs.self._parseArgs (/usr/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:990:30)
    at Object.self.runCommand (/usr/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/yargs/lib/command.js:204:45)
    at Object.Yargs.self._parseArgs (/usr/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:990:30)
    at Object.get [as argv] (/usr/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:927:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/cli.js:58:5)
```

I have changed the files to build the network and even I get the error with the example files:

File /home/testuser/test-network/lib/logic.js:

```
function sampleTransaction(tx) {

    // Save the old value of the asset.
    var oldValue = tx.asset.value;

    // Update the asset with the new value.
    tx.asset.value = tx.newValue;

    // Get the asset registry for the asset.
    return getAssetRegistry('org2.acme.sample2.SampleAsset')
        .then(function (assetRegistry) {

            // Update the asset in the asset registry.
            return assetRegistry.update(tx.asset);

        })
        .then(function () {

            // Emit an event for the modified asset.
            var event = getFactory().newEvent('org2.acme.sample2', 'SampleEvent');
            event.asset = tx.asset;
            event.oldValue = oldValue;
            event.newValue = tx.newValue;
            emit(event);
            });
    }
```

File /home/testuser/test-network/test.cto:

```
namespace org2.acme.sample2

asset SampleAsset identified by assetId {
  o String assetId
  --> SampleParticipant owner
  o String value
}

participant SampleParticipant identified by participantId {
  o String participantId
  o String firstName
  o String lastName
}

transaction SampleTransaction {
  --> SampleAsset asset
  o String newValue
}
event SampleEvent {
  --> SampleAsset asset
  o String oldValue
  o String newValue
}
```

I have tried to change the namespace too and I got the same error

Answer (score 1):

ok, its because you have multiple .cto files (ie in your directory) with the same namespace contained in them (perhaps you are making different editions or wanting multiple .cto files). The archive command checks for namespaces in each CTO). Each busness network model has a single namespace. All resource declarations within the file are implicitly in this namespace. You can have multiple .cto files if you want to break it out - but don't repeat the namespace in the additional files. You can even, if you want, have multiple model files, with different namespaces (if that's what you want of course).

See https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/cto_language.html

Otherwise, suggest to move any 'editions' of the CTO files with the same namespace name.

Then try build your .bna file again.